# Bitbucket plugin for jenkins not working. Response body return HTTP status: 302

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to setup the jenkins integration with bitbucket as per this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSxZYKea700&t=142s

I'm trying to make the following settings:

**In jenkins:**

- Respository: (my repos and credentials)
- Branches do build: "*/dev"
- In trigger I check "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket"

**In bitbucket:**

- In my project / configuration / Add Webhook, I set webhook with title "jenkins" and url "http://jenkins.b1solucoes.com.br/bitbucket-hook/"

All requests results in Response body return HTTP status: 302

someting wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please put your Jenkins webhook in project webhook configuration as follow: `http://<Name of Jenkins server>:8080/bitbucket-webhook/` If Jenkins is not running on 8080, then put the appropriate port where Jenkins is running in the URL.

Comment: I configured the nginx proxy-pass to point the subdomain to port 8080. It worked perfectly. Thank you!